# How can I connect to my Amazon EC2 instance if I lost my SSH key pair after its initial launch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, csr

I have an EC2 Ubuntu Instance and I have to SSH into to generate a CSR from it for a SSL that I will put on my website. But, I can't SSH into it as I lost the key pair associated with it.

I have followed method 1 on the official documentation by Amazon to connect to my EC2 instance and it still isn't working.

This is the official doc
Doc: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/user-data-replace-key-pair-ec2/

The steps I took were:

1. I created a new key pair.
2. I then retrieved the public key for the key pair.
3. I opened the Amazon EC2 console.
4. I stopped my instance.
5. I choose Actions -> Instance settings -> Edit user data.
6. I copied the following script into the Edit user data dialog box:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [users-groups, once]
users:
  - name: username
    ssh-authorized-keys: 
    - PublicKeypair
```

I replaced username with 'ubuntu' and replaced PublicKeypair with the public key retrieved in step 2. I entered the entire public key, starting with ssh-rsa.

7. I saved.
8. I started my instance again.
9. After the cloud-init phase was complete, I went to validate that the public key was replaced. But, it still showed the name of my previous instance under "Key Name" on the instance that I lost. Wasn't it supposed to change the name to the newly made key?
10. To connect into my instance, I went to my terminal to use SSH and the new key pair saved into my local machine.
11. However, I was denied.

What do I do now? I need to get my website running and the data on my website is not loading because the SSL expired.

Anyone faced something similar and fixed it?

Comment: The keypairs listed on the instance just shows the keypair used when the instance was initially launched. Don't be worried about what it shows. Not sure why the recommended method isn't working, but you can use `ssh -vvv` to turn on debugging to see how it is attempting to login. It will show they keypairs that it is trying to use. This might give some additional insight.

Comment: You can use webssh (e.g. ssm session manager) to connect without any ssh keys.